# Range validator to validate percentage value

Tags: asp.net, validation

I want to use `RangeValidator` to validate percentage value. For that I set minimum value as 0.0 and maximum value to 100.00, but its not working.  I tried using minimum value as 0% and maximum values as 100% but still not working.

Here is some code:

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="percentageRangeValidator" runat="server"
   ControlToValidate="percentageBox" Display="Dynamic" 
   ErrorMessage="Invalid Percentage" 
   MaximumValue="100.00" MinimumValue="0.00">*</asp:RangeValidator>
```

What's wrong in my method.

Comment: provide you html code please ..

Comment: @Akram Shadha... My HTML code is as below        <asp:RangeValidator ID="percentageRangeValidator" runat="server" 
                                            ControlToValidate="percentageBox" Display="Dynamic" 
                                            ErrorMessage="Invalid Percentage" MaximumValue="100.00" MinimumValue="0.00">*</asp:RangeValidator>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the type of the value `Type="Double"`:

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="percentageRangeValidator" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="percentageBox" Display="Dynamic" 
    ErrorMessage="Invalid Percentage" MaximumValue="100.00" MinimumValue="0.00" 
    Type="Double">*</asp:RangeValidator>
```

Comment: Awesome Chirag! I missed out Type cause it looked like a typeof() related property!

Answer (score 4):

Can you try this code which includes "Type=Double" in Range Validator control

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Type="Double" ErrorMessage="enter value bet ween 0 and 100" 
            MaximumValue="100.00" MinimumValue="0.00"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

Comment: @Chirag Please add Type=Double to your range validator

Comment: Awesome DSharper! I missed out Type cause it looked like a typeof() related property!

Answer (score 3):

You miss type attribute in you code. I am sending you an example code for this....

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" />
<asp:RangeValidator ID="rng1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt" Display="Dynamic"
     ErrorMessage="Invalid Percentage" SetFocusOnError="true" Text="Invalid Percentage"
     ValidationGroup="check" MinimumValue="0.00" MaximumValue="100" Type="Double" />
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" ValidationGroup="check" Text="Submit" />
```

Comment: @Gaurav Agraval... Thanks Gaurav.. But I did correction and now its working perfectly....